# Does this integral convergence result hold?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume that you have a sequence of random variables $X_i$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$. Assume that $E[|X_i|]<\infty$, for all $i$. Also assume that for each $\omega \in \Omega$ there is an $i^*(\omega)$ such that $X_i(\omega)=0$ for $i > i^*(\omega)$. This means that the random variable $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ converges everywhere.

**Question 1**

Do we have that

$$E\left[\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty X_i\right|\right]<\infty?$$

**Question 2**

If the answer to the previos question is yes, lets continue, if the answer to the previous question is no, then also require the inequality to hold.

Do we now have that

$$E\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty X_i\right]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty E\left[ X_i\right]?$$

Note that we have not assumed that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty E\left[ X_i\right]$ converges. Will it converge? If not, will the result hold if we assume that it converges?

Comment: 1 should hold... use the triangle inequality to pull the absolute value into the sum. Then use Beppo Levi to interchange expected value and sum

Answer (score 1):

Conclusion 2 is also false.

For a counterexample, define on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure a sequence $(X_n)$ of "alternating" rectangles that get narrower and taller as $n\to\infty$. So

- $X_1$ has constant value $1$, while $X_2:=-X_1$ is the opposite of $X_1$,
- $X_3$ is a rectangle of height $3$ over the interval $(0,\frac13)$, while $X_4:=-X_3$ is its opposite,
- $X_5$ is a rectangle of height $5$ over the interval $(0,\frac15)$, while $X_6:=-X_5$ is its opposite,

and so on. Then $(X_n)$ satisfy the hypotheses of your first paragraph. Check that $\sum X_n$ equals zero (pointwise), so clearly $E|\sum X_n|<\infty$. Meanwhile, $E(X_n)=(-1)^{n+1}$ so $\sum E(X_n)$ fails to converge.

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis is too weak to give the first conclusion. On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure define $X_n(\omega)=n$ if $0 <\omega <\frac 1 n$ and $0$ otherwise. Then the hypothesis is satisfied but your conclusion fails.